# Is firewire drive emulation (like Macs' target disk mode) possible with a PC?

Tags: windows, linux, firewire, emulation

Is there an application that allows one to 'export' a drive or virtual disk image to firewire so that the machine at the other end sees the computer as a regular firewire drive? Apple computers can do that via their [target disk mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1661) (hold down `t` on boot), but I am searching for an application that would work under Windows or Linux.

The goal is to boot an older Apple iBook, which can not boot from USB, via this emulated firewire drive.

Answer (score 1):

With the right firmware, sure. No PC has the right firmware.

Comment: Could you clarify?  Is this impossible because the hardware exerts too much control over the firewire port, meaning even a special driver wouldn't be able to make the port act like an external hard drive?  If so, do you happen to know if it's possible to host some kind of a network share over firewire that the Mac can find when you hold down Option?

Comment: PPC macs had special firmware that allowed for disc mode over openboot. intel macs, and common PCs don't.